# very Basic ember router example unsolved

Tags: ember.js

I tried this very basic ember router example following the ember-router-example. But when I run  it, it shows me an empty page. I checked the console window for any errors, but seems to be fine. Not really sure why this is not working and where am missing.

I am just trying to create the first level links of Home, Sections, items only.

Can somebody help me?

`index.html`:

```
    <body>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/jquery.lorem.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

           <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a {{action "doHome"}}>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a {{action "doSections"}}>Sections</a></li>
                    <li><a {{action "doItems"}}>Items</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

             <div>
            {{outlets}}
           </div>

           </script>


            <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
            <h1>yeah right Home</h1>
           </script>

           <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sections">
            <h1>Oh v in Sections index</h1>
           </script>


           <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
            <h1>correct in Items Index Page</h1>
           </script>
    </body>
```

`app.js` :

```
    $(function() {


    App = Ember.Application.create()


    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName:'application'
    });


    App.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.HomeView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName:'home'
    });

    App.SectionsController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.SectionsView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName:'sections'
    });


    App.ItemsController = Ember.Controller.extend();
    App.ItemsView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName:'items'
    });

    App.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
        root: Ember.Route.extend({
            doHome : function(router,event){
                router.transitionTo('home');
            },

            doSections:function(router,event){
                router.transitionTo('sections');
            },

            doitems:function(router,event){
                router.transitionTo('items');
            },

            home : Ember.Route.extend({
                route : '/',
                connectOutlets:function(router,event){
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
                }
            }),

            sections : Ember.Route.extend({
                route : '/sections',
                connectOutlets:function(router,event){
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sections');
                }
            }),

            items : Ember.Route.extend({
                route : '/items',
                connectOutlets:function(router,event){
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('items');
                }
        })

        })//root
}) //router

});
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Ember.js 1.0.0pre4 ?

Answer (score 2):

I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crUFE/) with your code. It seems to be working, just use latest *ember* and *handlebars*. And maybe you should change `{{outlets}}` with `{{outlet}}`.

#### EDIT

The above fiddle is not working, see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crUFE/2/).
I rewrote the routing code using the [*new routing API*](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/), now it is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks . I changed to {{outlet}} and the libs am using is all form the same ember-router-example codebase from github. Still i am surprised its working for you but not for me :(

Comment: Can you create a fiddle which reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are supposed to be using "template" as opposed to templateName when you are defining your templates in your main html file.  If you were to create those templates as separate handlebars files and use a build step, you would then use templateName to refer to them (by file name).

Steve